# Is using comparator "offtopic" bad java style?

Tags: java, coding-style

Thanks to @Thilo i mad the interface like this :

```
public interface compareOp<T> {
     public boolean compare(T op1, T op2);
}
```

And the "implementers":

```
private static final compareOp<Integer> GreaterThan = new compareOp<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public boolean compare(Integer x, Integer y) {
        if (x > y)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};
private static final compareOp<Integer> SameThan = new compareOp<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public boolean compare(Integer x, Integer y) {
        if (x == y)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};
private static final compareOp<Integer> LessThan = new compareOp<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public boolean compare(Integer x, Integer y) {
        if (x < y)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};
```

I have writte som code where i do a comparsion
i need this code three times for grater, equal less but i dont wanted to duplicate the code so i made a parameter comp type comparator  and check :

```
if (comp.compare(output1[i][n1], output2[j][n2]) == 0)
```

my comparators cant be used for normal sorting because they violate the -1,0,1 rules but i dont use them for other things

Is this bad Style regarding Java rules ?

here is the code of my comparators:

```
private static final Comparator<Integer> GreaterThen = new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer x, Integer y) {
        if (x > y)
            return 0;
        return -1;
    }
};
private static final Comparator<Integer> SameThen = new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer x, Integer y) {
        if (x == y)
            return 0;
        if (x > y)
            return 1;
        return -1;

    }
};
private static final Comparator<Integer> LessThen = new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer x, Integer y) {
        if (x < y)
            return 0;
        return 1;
    }
};
```

and thats how i use them:

```
    new Helpers().subSetsCompared(input1, 3, input2, 4, GreaterThen);
    new Helpers().subSetsCompared(input1, 3, input2, 4, SameThen);
    new Helpers().subSetsCompared(input1, 3, input2, 4, LessThen);
```

Comment: If you're concerned about style, you might also consider using the word "than" instead of "then".

Comment: good point i will refactor this ;)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - with your GreaterThan and LesserThan comparators, `compare(x, x);` returns -1: do you really want that? You should give more information about why you are doing that because there is probably a better way.

Comment: LessThan and GreaterThan seems to break contract.

Comment: yes i know they braek contract, tahts what i wrote above, but i can compare only on 0 in the code so they have to give back zero when they are greater repect. samller

Comment: Shouldn't interfaces start with capital? (Since you're concerned with style)

Comment: I'd also be included not to write this kind of thing myself, and use something like Guava's Range: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html and related utilities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those are not "real" Comparators, and you only call them from your own code, then you might as well define your own interface. That seems cleaner to me.

Comment: +1 Absolutely. Breaking the contract is a bad idea. Just create your own contract.

Comment: i will do so, didn´t thought about that, thats i rewrite comparator except that i call it myCompare and can use boolean instead of sgn

Comment: Call it `BinaryPredicate`.